# DOMElement does not seem to be removed from DOMNodeList

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

Plase, help!
Need to **delete** 1st element from `DOMNodeList $myDivs`, but actual removal dosen't occur - element remains.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($file);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$myDivs = $xpath->query('//div[@data-name|data-price]');
usleep(1);
//Must REVERSE iterate DOMNodeList.
for ($i = $myDivs->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  //Deleting 1st element of (DOMNodeList) $myDivs, containing advertisement product
  if ($i == 0) {
  //Removing div element (DOMNode) from DOM? DOMNodeList? Nothing changes
    $result = $myDivs->item($i)->parentNode->removeChild($myDivs->item($i));
  }
  //Adding formatted string of attributes of valid DOMElements (div)
  $outputArr[] = printf('%1$s - %2$s, %3$s.<br>',
                        $myDivs->item($i)->getAttribute('data-name'),
                        $myDivs->item($i)->getAttribute('data-price'),
                        $myDivs->item($i)->getAttribute('data-currency'))
                    ?? null;
}
```

`for(){}` reverse iterates through `$myDivs`, fetched by XPath and at last iteration (`$i=0`, element #0) DOMElement should be purged from everywhere (DOM and DOMNodeList), as it seems from php.net:

> [Keep in mind that DOMNodelists are "live" - changes to the document or node that the DOMNodelist was derived from will be reflected in the DOMNodelist.](http://php.net/manual/ru/domnodelist.item.php#78826)
>
> [You can modify, and even delete, nodes from a DOMNodeList if you iterate backwards](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domnodelist.php#83390)

But it doesn't happen!

No errors occur, `$result` equals that exact element #0 (meaning `removeChild()` has done it's job correctly)

While debugging I get `$myDivs->length=31` at line `usleep(1);`, and at line `$outputArr[] =...` I still have same length of `$myDivs`.
So, element #0 still gets appended to `$ouputArr`, while shouldn't...

Can't see what I'm missing...

P.S. of course, is such situation one can always just use `continue` to jump through iteration, but what about *deleting*?

Comment: I bet it is adding the item in position 1 twice

Comment: @PatrickQ, not exactly. Later in code I'm printing `$outputArr`. So, I'm sure that element #0 gets into `$outputArr`, while souhldn't. It has unique content, so no doubt about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not quoting the official documentation but remarks contributed by users. DOMNodeLists returned from XPath queries aren't "live". `removeChild` only removes the node from the original document, not from the DOMNodeList.

Comment: Well, yes. Official documentation doesn't say a word about altering _any_ DOMNodeLists. Likewise about any differece between DOMNodeLists from DOMDocument and DOMXPath... 
So, there's no way to edit DOMNodeLists resulted from XPath query?

Comment: @Denis.Z Yes, there's no way to alter DOMNodeLists *directly*. Some lists can change indirectly if the original document is changed, but I think this only applies to lists returned by `DOMNode::childNodes`.