# DOMXpath query() doesn't provide expected contextual fetching

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

Help greatly appreciated.

Can't make DOMXpath pull necessary DOMNodes in context.
Somehow at each `for` iteration `$a` is a DOMNodeList (length=31)  of what seems to be *all* `<a>` from the whole DOM **instead** of expected children of *only one* `$childNode` from all (and length should be 4).

IMHO: To me it feels like *context* remains at the root of html rather than changing accordingly to `foreach`... If so, is it possible to alter its behavior as reqiured?

P.S. **Vuola!**, have tried changed Xpath query `$a = $xpath->query('.')` and recieved `DOMElement->tagName="html"`.
So, in addition to [my previous question on DOMXpath DOMNodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46448006/domelement-does-not-seem-to-be-removed-from-domnodelist) it seems that DOMDocument doesn't give a hell about DOMXpath. No connection between theese two, no context usage available...

Answer: Meh, it's just me being blind idiot..have missed 2nd parameter of DOMXpath::query()

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom -> loadHTML('HTML data');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$myDivs = $xpath -> query('//div[@price]');

for($i=0; $i <= $myDivs->length-1; $i++) {

  $childNodes = $myDivs->item($i)->childNodes;

  foreach($childNodes as $childNode){
    $a=$xpath->query('.//a[@data-image-src]');

     if($a){
       usleep(1);
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the *context node* as a second argument to the [`DOMXPath::query()`](http://php.net/domxpath.query) method.

In your particular case, that would be:

```
$a = $xpath->query('.//a[@data-image-src]', $childNode);
```

Comment: That is great! In future, if you ask a question here and find out the answer yourself, it is a good idea to come back and write an answer.  This way, you will help anyone else who has the same question. :)